# I am trying to save product price inside billProduct table in every bill created

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can I take price column and cost price from Product table and save it to BillProducts Table when creating Bill?

This is the BillProducts Model Where I need to insert price and cost price in every time I create a bill

```php
class BillProduct extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'bill_id', 'product_id', 'quantity', 'unit', 'packing', 'remark', 'discount','price','cost_price'
    ];

    protected $appends = ['price','profit'];

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class)->withDefault();
    }
}
```

Also, I have a product table where I do store all products information:

```php
class Product extends Model {
    use Translatable;

    public $translatedAttributes = ['description', 'title'];
    public $translationModel = ProductTranslation::class;

    const FILLABLE = ['price', 'quantity', 'cost_price', 'supplier_id','item_code'];
    protected $fillable = self::FILLABLE;

    public function createTranslation(Request $request) {
        foreach (locales() as $key => $language) {
            foreach ($this->translatedAttributes as $attribute) {
                $this->{$attribute . ':' . $key} = $request->get($attribute . '_' . $key);
            }
            $this->save();
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function billProduct() {
        return $this->hasMany(BillProduct::class);
    }
}
```

Now every time I choose a product when creating a bill I need to save the product price also in billProducts Table

I need to do that to avoid changing the bill total when updating any product

Also, I use this function in the model to create products in billProducts

```php
public function createProducts(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($this->billProducts ?? [] as $billProduct) {
        $billProduct->product->updateQuantity($billProduct->quantity);
        $billProduct->delete();
    }
    $dataArr = [
        'status' => true,
        'item' => $this
    ];

    foreach ($request->products ?? [] as $product) {
        $productObj = Product::findOrFail($product['product_id']);
        if ($productObj->updateQuantity(-1 * $product['quantity'])) {
            $product['bill_id'] = $this->id;
            BillProduct::create($product);
        } else {
            $dataArr['status'] = false;
        }
    }
    $this->save();

    return $dataArr;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `Product` model has a `hasMany` relation with `billProduct()`, so :

```
$data = Product::findOrFail($product['product_id']); // parent row
$data->billProduct()->create(['unit' => 1, 'price' => 123]); // product_id filled by eloquent
```

Comment: you might need to use ->each() after billProduct()

Comment: @Tatek if OP needs to insert multiple row then each() or createMany() can do this job too